# Codekit file permission issues (Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /.sass-cache)

Tags: ruby, sass, permissions, compass-sass, codekit

Getting the following error:

```
Compiling failed with this error: Errno::EROFS on line ["239"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /.sass-cache
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Really painful, any help would be appreciated.

Happened after my update to Mac OS Catalina.
Currently on 10.15.1 (19B88).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby Sass is deprecated.
In Codekit 3 you should use libsass compiler instead.
Libsass is not available if you use Compass.
If so, you can set the cache location path in the config.rb:

sass_options = { :cache_location => '/tmp/sass_cache' }

Comment: For versions 3.12.1+, Dart Sass is now the default sass compiler. You will still need to add `sass_options = { :cache_location => '/tmp/sass_cache' }` in your config.rb with Dart Sass.

Answer (score 1):

`/.sass-cache` would be a Sass cache directory at the *root of your file system*. It should not be trying to create that directory there.

However this Ruby is getting run, it's not running with the right working directory, or needs to be passed a base path to run in.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: @AsaadMahmood I don't know. You didn't include any info in your question to indicate what you're running to get this error

Comment: I get this error when compiling through "Codekit" https://codekitapp.com/.

Answer (score 0):

In Catalina, the disk root where Ruby Sass attempts to write that cache is now read-only, so it fails.

I used Bourbon instead. I also created some of the mixins that were in compass myself.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
line_comments = false
output_style = :compressed
sourcemap = true
asset_cache_buster = :none 
cache = false
```

to my config.rb file fixed this for me.