# Unable to save sass (.scss) files on atom mac

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass, atom-editor

I have been trying to use sass files but whenever I try to save the file I get the error

```
Command failed: sass "/Users/bechara/Desktop/<path of the file>/test.scss" "/Users/bechara/Desktop/<path of the file>/test.css"
Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.sass-cache
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I have the latest build of node.js installed and tried installing node-sass with npm.
The packages I tried on atom are "build-sass", "atom-sass", "sass", and "sass-autocompile".

I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Sass is not able to create `.sass-cache` directory because parent directory is `read-only`. You can change permissions in Finder or type `chmod 755 directoryName`.

Answer (score 1):

Can be addressed by modifying your `sass_options` in your `config.rb` file to specify a writable cache location.

```
sass_options = { :cache_location => '/tmp/sass_cache' }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300639/308860) to [Codekit file permission issues (Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /.sass-cache)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58937978/4424636).